# How to get a notification when someone links to your web page

Tags: notifications

I'm kind of wondering what the professional and/or easy way to do this is.

I know about [WhoLinksToMe](http://wholinkstome.com/) and [pingbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pingback) and their cousins but I'm not sure if that's all that's out there. What do you use, what does everybody else use and what's good?

P.S. Feel free to reword this, someone. It feels poorly written to me. Sorry about that.

Comment: This is not computer related, sorry. You can check the FAQ to see what's covered by SU.

Comment: Weird, seems computer related to me. People post internet questions on here all the time and my previous questions like this haven't been closed. Well, at least I got an answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts) work well.

Comment: How would you use Google Alerts for this application?

Comment: Into the search terms field, put " link:nathanial.com/blog" or whatever. Whenever someone links to you, you'll get an email.